# How to make a figure in the center of the page in Latex?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I'm writing a assignment report with latex. I find the figure is always slightly on the right of the page even I use \centering or \begin{center}. I wish to make the figure exactly on the center of the page. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a minimal , yet complete, code of what you tried. It's  impossible to help efficiently  *in abstracto*.

Comment: Check (with `\fbox{\includegraphics{<image>}}` if the image has spurious white space on the left or right side.

Comment: I detected that centering sometimes does not work peoperly, if the Image is too large. You may use scalebox{factor}{contents} to reduce the size slightly. Then \begin{center} should work.